# Input lose focus on click in paper-dialog Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x, paper-dialog

I am using Paper-dialog and paper-dialog-scrollable webcomponents in Polymer projects. I have some set of input fields (Forms) on paper-dialog (pop-up). By default when opening popup(Dialog) I am focusing input field.

But issue is when i click, scroll anywhere inside the dialog, Input lose it focus. How should i keep focus inside paper-dialog even if i click/scroll

i tried below code but no luck. form code wrote inside another element called my-form-element

```
   <paper-dialog-scrollable id="myDialog">
        <my-form-element></my-form-element>
   </paper-dialog-scrollable>



Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender( this, function() {
     const dialogContent = this.$.myDialog.$.scrollable;
     dialogContent.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
      });
 });
```

Comment: Input lose its focus mean, your dialog is closed when you click out of dialog?  and need to re-open or?

Comment: I have FORM(SignUp) inside DIALOG. Dialog has max-height and width and given overflow : auto. problem here is when i click SCROLL. paper-input lose it focus which is inside DIALOG. it should not lose focus on SCROLL. @HakanC

Comment: try `this.$.myDialog.autofocus = true`  Not sure. There are some options more. But if you could provide an online test place like  https://stackblitz.com or somehow. Than can test dome options.:) (myDialog , this id may replace with `paper-input 's id`